# Duda Buscador ID cliente php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, subconsultas

Edito el post con la solución:
RESUMEN: Lo que queremos es que al buscar el id de cliente, me muestre el registro completo del cliente.

(Variar la tabla al gusto o necesidad)
Código resolución al problema:

```
      <form method="POST" action="" onSubmit="return validarForm(this)"> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresar código de cliente" name="palabra">     
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">     
      </form>
      </center>
        <?php

        require('conexion.php');

        /* Variable para el control de errores*/
        $arrMensaje=array();
        /*
                *1ª evaluación: ¿la conexión está activa?
                *Este sería el primer paso antes de lanzar cualquier código
                *relativo a la base de datos
        */
        if ($mysqli){
            /*
                    *CONSULTA PARA PREPARAR
                    *En estas consultas en vez de los valores pone el signo ?
                    *Habrá tantos signos ?  como valores externos se requieran
                    *Aquí sólo se usa uno, pero pueden ser más
            */
            $buscar = $_POST["palabra"];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id like '%$buscar%'";
            /*
                    *VALORES
                    *Generalmente los valores son recuperados por $_POST o $_GET
                    *Aquí lo ponemos directamente por motivos de simplicidad
                    *Un valor recuperado por POST sería algo así más o menos: $id=$_POST["id"];
                    *La consulta buscará los actores cuyo id sea mayor que 0 y menor que 8
            */


            /*
                    *PREPARAR LA CONSULTA
            */

            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

            /*
                    *2ª evaluación: ¿La consulta se preparó bien?
                    *Dado que el método prepare invocado antes devuelve FALSE
                    *si hay algún error, podemos preguntar si $stmt es TRUE
                    *Si no lo es, significa que hubo un error en la consulta
            */

            if ($stmt) {

                /*
                      * Si la consulta se preparó bien, ahora le pasamos aparte los valores
                      * Este es el núcleo de las consultas preparadas
                      * Se usa aquí bind_param para pasar los valores
                      * IMPORTANTE: Aquí se pasan tantos valores como signos de ? haya en la instrucción $sql
                      * como la instrucción tenía un sólo ?, pasamos un solo valor
                      * cuando hay más valores, estos deben pasarse en el orden en que aparecen en $sql
                      * Las "ii"  indican el tipo de dato de esa columna en la base de datos
                      * en este caso son numéricos, si fuesen cadenas, en vez de "i" habría "s"
                      * si fuese uno numérico y otro cadena entonces tendríamos "is", y así por el estilo...
                */

                $stmt->bind_param("i", $buscar); //Si idusuario es VARCHAR cambia la "i" por una "s"
                $stmt->execute();

                /*
                        * ALMACENAR LOS RESULTADOS
                        * mysqli tiene un problema cuando se trata de almacenar los resultados
                        * en arrays asociativos usando consultas preparadas
                        * por eso es invocado aquí el método get_result hecho a mano
                        * ya que éste sólo funciona en servidores con mysqlnd instalado
                        * el método get_result puede ser guardado en una clase utilitaria
                        * y llamarlo mediante una nueva instancia de esa clase cuando lo necesitemos
                        * o, si hacemos muchas operaciones de este tipo, recomiendo pasar de mysqli a PDO
                */

                $arrResultado=get_result($stmt);

                /*
                        * CONSTRUIR LA TABLA
                        * En vez de mezlcar constantemente código HTML/PHP
                        * Lo cual hace el código más difícil de leer y analizar
                        * Podemos crear toda nuestra tabla en una variable PHP que iremos concatenando
                        * Y la imprimimos al final
                */


                /* Primera parte de nuestra tabla */
                $strHTML='<table>
                                <thead>
                                    <th >Codigo</th>
                                    <th >Optica</th>
                                    <th >Nombre</th>
                                    <th >Apellidos</th>
                                    <th >Provincia</th>
                                    <th >Agente</th>
                                    <th >Telefono</th>                            
                                 </thead>
                                 <tbody>';

                /* Leemos el array obtenido antes y seguimos concatenando cada fila/columnas */


                foreach ($arrResultado as $row)
                {
                    $strHTML.='<tr>';
                    $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["id"]."</td>";
                    $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["ncomercial"]."</td>";
                    $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["nombre"]."</td>";
                    $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["apellidos"]."</td>";
                    $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["provincia"]."</td>";
                    $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["asignaragente"]."</td>";
                    $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["telefono"]."</td>";
                    $strHTML.='</tr>';

                }

                /* Una vez fuera del bucle, completamos la tabla */

                $strHTML.='</tbody>';
                $strHTML.='</table>';

                /*Completada la tabla, la imprimimos*/

                echo $strHTML;

                /* Cerramos el $stmt */

                $stmt->close();

            }else{

                /*
                    * Llenamos el array de control de errores con un mensaje
                    * Podemos usar el método error de $mysqli para saber qué error es
                */

                $arrMensaje=array("error"=>"Hubo un fallo en la consulta: ".$mysqli->error);

            }


            /* Cerramos la conexión */

            $mysqli->close();


        }else{

                /*
                    * Llenamos el array de control de errores con un mensaje
                    * Podemos usar el método error de $mysqli para saber qué error es
                */

            $arrMensaje=array("error"=>"La conexión es nula: ".$mysqli->error);
        }


        /* 
            * VERIFICAR SI HUBO ERROR
            * Aquí leemos $arrMensaje para ver si contiene algo
            * Si hay algo significa que algún error fue capturado en la ejecución del código
            * entonces podremos imprimirlo
            * Esta forma de proceder la he copiado de los servicos REST, que siempre devuelven algo
            * es una buena práctica hacer decir siempre algo al código
            * o sea, no escribir código mudo cuando falle algo
        */
        if ($arrMensaje){
            echo $arrMensaje["error"];
        }


        /*
            * FUNCION QUE EMULA EL FETCH_ASSOC DE PDO
            * Esta función nos permite crear un array asociativo con los resultados
            * Así accedemos fácimente a su valor por el nombre de columna en la base de datos
        */

        function get_result( $Statement ) {
            $RESULT = array();
            $Statement->store_result();
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
                $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
                $PARAMS = array();
                while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
                    $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
                }
                call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
                $Statement->fetch();
            }
            return $RESULT;
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? Puedes en primer lugar depurar tu consulta, haciendo `echo`de esto: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id like '%$buscar%' or nombre like '%$buscar%'` y ejecutándolo en phpmyAdmin por ejemplo.

Comment: No me devuelve ningún dato tampoco desde phpmyadmin.  Al escribir por ejemplo en el buscador el "1" me devuelve las cabeceras de las tablas, pero no me muestra el cliente 1.

Comment: Entonces imagínate, si los criterios de la consulta no se cumplen es imposible que obtengas datos. Debes probar con datos en los que se cumplan los criterios... no obstante, tu código debe estar escrito de forma que sepa manejar esa eventualidad, mostrando mensajes adecuados cuando los criterios no se cumplan.

Comment: SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id like '%$buscar%' sustituyendo el '%$buscar%' por un 1, para phpmyadmin, me muestra el cliente 1, pienso que el problema esta en la conexión a la base de datos

Comment: Cuando tú escribes un código, ese código debe hacer lo que tú le digas. Por lo tanto, debes ir controlando su flujo de forma que sepas en todo momento lo que ocurre. *Control 1*: ¿La conexión funciona? Si no funciona debes emitir un mensaje de conexión nula. *Control 2*: ¿La consulta está bien escrita?. Si no lo está, debes emitir un mensaje al respecto. *Control 3:* ¿La consulta devuelve datos?. Si no devuelve debes emitir un mensaje al respecto. Y así sucesivamente... Tú eres el programador, y no puedes escribir un código que haga lo que le parezca.

Comment: He intentado adaptar, el código completo con el que tu me ayudastes hace un par de días.  En el formulario recojo el dato que me interesa, y lo guardo dentro del php como "$buscar = $_POST["palabra"];"    Luego en la consulta, intento que al buscar el id.. " id = '%$buscar%' " Voy a seguir revisando que es lo que puede suceder

Comment: Me parece extraño que uses `LIKE` con una columna id. ¿Esa columna es numérica? Generalmente las columnas `id`  se usan para identificar registros únicos, no le veo sentido a un `LIKE` en un id.

Comment: Acabo de descubrir el error. y ha sido gracias a tu código, quiero darte las gracias de nuevo, me has ayudao más de lo que imaginas en tu comentario, creo que es necesario llevar un control. de todo paso que se va siguiendo. El problema, que esta resolviendo el valor del buscar, despues de la consulta, al añadirlo antes de.. SI que me encuentra el valor. Mil gracias!

Comment: Voy a actualizar el POST, con la resolución del problema. Para que veas como he conseguido resolverlo, y si alguien lo necesitara en un futuro, poder utilizarlo!

Comment: Pero debo decirte que aquí: `$sql = "SELECT *  FROM usuarios WHERE id = '%$buscar%';` estás haciendo tu código totalmente inseguro... escribir una consulta así viola la regla de usar consultas preparadas. Tu código es 100% vulnerable a inyección SQL nada más por esa simple línea. Lee lo que pone precisamente en el comentario del código justo arriba de esa línea. Es importante que entiendas bien ese principio de programación.

Comment: Para adaptar el código a consultas preparadas: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id like ?";` Luego la variable `$buscar='%'.$_POST["palabra"].'%';`  y el bind: `$stmt->bind_param("s", $buscar);`, cambias la `i` por una `s`, porque estás pasando un string. De ese modo el código será seguro.

Comment: Que te parece esta modificación:                                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id like ?"; Entiendo que cuando recibo un valor, de donde sea, puedo establecer el " ? "

Comment: Genial! Todo modificado y sigue en funcionamiento! Muchas gracias A. Cedano de nuevo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se resolvería con tres sencillos pasos:

1. Escribir tu `$sql` como una consulta preparada. Por lo tantas veces dicho sobre la Inyección SQL:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id LIKE ?";
   ```
2. Preparar bien la variable que vas a  pasar para usar con `LIKE`. Nótese que en consultas preparadas los `%` que rodean el valor que `LIKE` evaluará se colocan en la variable, no en la consulta propiamente:

   ```
   $buscar='%'.$_POST["palabra"].'%';
   ```
3. Hay que cambiar el tipo de dato que se pasa en `bind_param`. Dado que estaremos pasando una cadena, cambiamos la `i` por la `s`:

   ```
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $buscar);
   ```

Con esto el código no sólo funcionará, sino que será un código seguro.

4. Finalmente, al código le falta un control suplementario. ¿Qué pasa si no se cumplen los criterios de búsqueda? Actualmente el código te presentará una tabla sólo con encabezados en ese caso. Esa parte se puede controlar de la siguiente forma:

   Después de obtener los resultados:

   ```
   $arrResultado=get_result($stmt);
   ```

Comprobamos si `$arrResultado` no está en blanco antes de construir la tabla:

```
    if ($arrResultado){
            $strHTML='<table>
                            <thead>
                                <th >Codigo</th>
                                <th >Optica</th>
                                <th >Nombre</th>
                                <th >Apellidos</th>
                                <th >Provincia</th>
                                <th >Agente</th>
                                <th >Telefono</th>                            
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>';

            /* Leemos el array obtenido antes y seguimos concatenando cada fila/columnas */


            foreach ($arrResultado as $row)
            {
                $strHTML.='<tr>';
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["id"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["ncomercial"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["nombre"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["apellidos"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["provincia"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["asignaragente"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["telefono"]."</td>";
                $strHTML.='</tr>';

            }

            /* Una vez fuera del bucle, completamos la tabla */

            $strHTML.='</tbody>';
            $strHTML.='</table>';

            /*Completada la tabla, la imprimimos*/

            echo $strHTML;
    }else{
        $arrMensaje=array("error"=>"No se cumplieron los criterios de búsqueda");
    }
```